# WPF: Listbox DisplayMember

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

Im using Listbox to present a table.
It uses DisplayMemberPath to present items.

How can i do multi binding for displaying items?

Lets say i want to display ID and NAME ... is there a template example or such?

thnx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `DataTemplate`.

### Example:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
                        <Binding Path="ID" />
                        <Binding Path="Name" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<ListView BorderThickness="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,10,0,0" Height="Auto" Name="buyerDetailListView" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Serial" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```